# angularJS global filter module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-module

I am having trouble getting my custom filter to work.

I have a module of global filters:

```
angular.module('globalFilters', []).filter('dateRange', function () {
    return function(item) {
        console.log(item);
        return true;
    }
});
```

This is injected into my app on creation. 
I am trying to apply this to an ng-repeat:

```
tr.pointer(ng-repeat="asset in completed | dateRange", ng-animate="'animate'", ng-click="selectAsset(asset);")
    td {{asset.Name}}
```

However adding this filter will filter all `assets` out of table. To try to isolate the problem I am returning true for the function to display all `assets` but it is not working.

Upon logging `item` to the console, result appears to be an array of all `assets` so I guess something is wrong.

I was following this tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using jade templating, renders to: <tr class="pointer" ng-repeat="asset in completed | dateRange" ng-animate="'animate'" ng-click="selectAsset(asset);"</tr>     <td>{{asset.Name}}</td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering an array...so your filter function needs to return an array.

```
.filter('dateRange', function () {
    return function(itemArray) {
        if(!itemArray){
            return null
        }else{
             return itemArray.filter(function(item){
                 // conditions of filter
             });
        }            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a custom filter function, the value passed into the filter is replaced by the value returned from the filter, so you are replacing `item` with `true`.

For a filter which logs the input without changing it, just return the input:

```
return function(item) {
    console.log(item);

    return item;
}
```